# Three.js get's very slow after removing and creating objects

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I'm new to three.js and I'm trying out a very basic shooter. The user should shoot a colored crate (box). When he does so, the crate disappears and another random crate appears, and so on.

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
             intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
                  scene.remove(object);
                  create_cube();
                  animate();
...
```

On landing, it works very smoothly. No lag at all. But the more boxes I shoot, the more the game begins to lag.

Am I doing something wrong in terms of memory allocation or garbage collection?

Here's a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0s2nmru/

(while my code works fine as a separate page, it doesn't seem to work when placed inside JSfiddle)

Update:

I've added stats that come with three.js. They keep giving me pretty good frames per second (up to 150 and more), even though the game starts to lag. Maybe I didn't implement it the right way?

Comment: In addition to Vals suggestions you might consider object pooling.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance, I see 3 ways to optimize your code

1) Don't call animate or render when it isn't necessary

```
    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
        var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3();
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        mouse3D.normalize();
        controls.getDirection(mouse3D);
        raycaster.set(controls.getObject().position, mouse3D);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
     intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
          scene.remove(object);
          create_cube();
          animate();     //  DON'T DO THIS

        }
        renderer.render(scene, camera);   //  DON'T DO THIS
      }
```

The render is done in a tight loop, controlled by requestAnimationFrame. Not only you don't need to call them outside of the loop, you are ruining the requestAnimationFrame optimizations if you do it (there are several instances of the loop running concurrently)

2) always try to make the render optimal.

```
     controls.getObject().translateX(velocity.x * delta);
     controls.getObject().translateY(velocity.y * delta);
     controls.getObject().translateZ(velocity.z * delta);

     if (controls.getObject().position.y < 10) {
```

Why not create a temporary variable with the result of controls.getObject() ?

3) Reuse whatever you can

In the line of yomotsu answer, but a little bit different : why not turn  off the visibility of the cube that has been hit, change its color and position, and make it visible again ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I implemented your 3 ways of optimization, and it works fluently now (AND I learned some new things!). I think number 1 had the most performance gain. On a different note: do you know why the stats kept showing decent frames per second? Did I put it on the right place in my code?

Comment: When you have several renders running concurrently, your frame rates can even be higher then ever (requestAnimationFrame should probably avoid you to hit 150fps in a standard PC since the card refresh rate is usually lower) but that doesn't mean this is useful work)

Answer (score 1):

When you remove a object, you have to remove geometry material and texture which used in the object as well. because resources are cached in the renderer.

```
scene.remove( mesh );
// clean up
geometry.dispose();
material.dispose();
texture.dispose();
```

Check this example.
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_test_memory

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried adding `scene.remove( object ); geometrycube3.dispose(); materialcube3.dispose();` to my code after the click is detected, but it doesn't seem to fix the lag issue. Am I doing something wrong? Didn't use `texture.dispose();` since my boxes haven't got a texture, just a color.